# Change Symfony Form Type element's form group CSS class

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

**Briefly**: I want to edit my **form elements** parent div class. In this code don't add or edit the css class to my target div (which is form-group) and **the follow Form Type is an element of another Form Type.**

I have an Form Type like the follow:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('id', IntegerType::class, [
        'empty_data' => '',
        'label' => 'ID',
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'col-sm-3'
        ],
    ]);
    $builder->add('companyName', TextType::class, [
        'empty_data' => '',
        'label' => 'Şirket Adı',
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'col-sm-3'
        ],
    ]);
}
```

So this form type renderin this HTML:

```
<div class="form-group  field-member_earning_filter"><label class="control-label"> </label>
<div id="form_filters_member" css="col-sm-11">
    <div class="form-group  field-integer"><label class="control-label"
                                                    for="form_filters_member_id">ID</label><input type="number"
                                                                                                  id="form_filters_member_id"
                                                                                                  name="form_filters[member][id]"
                                                                                                  class="form-control col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group  field-text"><label class="control-label" for="form_filters_member_companyName">Ticari
            Ünvan</label><input type="text" id="form_filters_member_companyName"
                                name="form_filters[member][companyName]" class="form-control col-sm-3"></div>
```

As you can see the CSS class which I want to add for each elements group are added to form-control element. But actually I want to do this:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-3 field-integer"><label class="control-label"
                                                    for="form_filters_member_id">ID</label><input type="number"
                                                                                                  id="form_filters_member_id"
                                                                                                  name="form_filters[member][id]"
                                                                                                  class="form-control">
```

I tried to refactor this challenge at view layer (on twig side) but actually doesn't have any real block to edit that "form group" section. Additionally that it's a form type in another form type for that reason the block don't affect my code. I mean this :

```
    {% block form_row %}
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3"> <--! but this form group actually my form type's form group -->
             {{ form_label(field) }}
             {{ form_errors(field) }}
             {{ form_widget(field) }}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. It's little bit workaround or hacking means but solved my problem:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  $builder->add('id', IntegerType::class, [
    'empty_data' => '',
    'label' => 'ID',
    'block_prefix' => ' col-sm-3'
]);
  $builder->add('companyName', TextType::class, [
    'empty_data' => '',
    'label' => 'Şirket Adı',
    'block_prefix' => ' col-sm-3'
]);
}
```

This form-group's div is just  affecting from `block_` options. As you guess the `block_prefix` is a prefix of class but just adding a whitespace () then it's solve my problem :)